# Getting a 4TB USB drive (4k native sector size) to work with Xen and Windows 2008 guest

Tags: hard-drive, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, xen, sectors

I am trying to get a new 4TB Seagate USB drive to work with Xen 6.2 and a Windows 2008 R2 virtual guest.

The Xen host sees the drive fine, `fdisk -l` lists it with the correct capacity, etc.  I can even use **gdisk** to create a partition and format it with **ext3**, then mount and transfer data with no problems.
However, I tried to create a local SR with XenCenter but the process fails at the point I attempt to add a virtual disk of any size.

I also tried **Attach Disk** to directly attach to the virutal guest, where it is detected by Windows, but due to the drive having 4k native sector size, the capacity reported is 30+ TB, and any attempts to perform operations on the drive yield I/O errors.

I installed the 4k sector support patch to Windows 2008 R2, but Disk Manager still shows a 30+TB drive. (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2510009), and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982018))

Am I going to have to return this drive and purchase one with emulated 512 byte sectors?  Or can anyone point me to a solution?

Thank you!

Updates:

Here's a screenshot:
[image: (29,808.19 GB) – Ryan Griggs Jan 7 at 2:33]

Attempts to initialize yield I/O errors.

I found [a note by someone on Amazon](http://amazon.com/review/R23TAL1IWYVO74/ref=cm_srch_res_rtr_alt_2) stating that the Seagate drive has native 4k sectors and doesn't work with Windows Backup/etc.

Hotfix for windows 7/2008 R2 only supports 512e disks, not native 4k: [support.microsoft.com/kb/2553708](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553708)

More info here about support for native 4k. Looks like only Windows 8 and Server 2012 support it.

[Using 4k disks with Hyper-V](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2515143)